# WPF Visibility Issue Windows Server 2003

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, telerik

I am currently developing a WPF application in .NET v4.0.

I have two grids which are shown hidden based on a property in my ViewModel:

```
<Grid Name="Results" Grid.Column="1" Visibility="{Binding ShowSearch, Converter={StaticResource Bvc}}">

<Grid Name="ProvisionalStreet" Grid.Column="1" Visibility="{Binding ShowProvisional, Converter={StaticResource Bvc}}">
```

When the user clicks a button the DelegateCommand does the following:

```
this.ShowProvisional = true;
this.ShowSearch = false;
```

ShowProvisional setter:

```
set
{
    this.showProvisional = value;
    this.RaisePropertyChanged(() => this.ShowProvisional);
}
```

ShowSearch setter:

```
set
{
    this.showSearch = value;
    this.RaisePropertyChanged(() => this.ShowSearch);
}
```

The code works fine on my local machine (Windows 7) in Visual Studio 2012, or when I double click the executable in the build directory. However our testers are logging into Citrix which is a Windows Server 2003 environment, and when they click the button nothing happens.

However if I assign `Visibility="{Binding ShowProvisional, Converter={StaticResource Bvc}}"` to a label or textbox for example it works for them.

Any ideas? Pretty much the same problem as [WPF issues with Windows Server 2003](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4730019/wpf-issues-with-windows-server-2003) but no answers were given.

Much appreciated

EDITED:

```
<BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="Bvc" />
```

EDITED:

```
        [ImportingConstructor]
        public GazetteerView(GazetteerViewModel viewModel)
            : this()
        {
            this.DataContext = viewModel;
        }
```

Comment: Well, maybe not related, but how does your `RaisePropertyChanged` look like? And what do you mean by "However if I assign `Visibility="..."`"?

Comment: @Andrew Rayner, i second Jeff for the RaisePropertyChanged request - please provide. Also, can we see the code for the Bvc converter?

Comment: My experience with WPF on XP makes me think this is a bug of the System/Driver of video adapter. May be not related but you can have a try:http://support.microsoft.com/kb/955692

Comment: I am inheriting from NotificationObject which is part of Prism, and contains the RaisePropertyChanged() method.

Comment: @zaitsman I have updated my post with the Bvc convertor

Comment: @AndrewRayner 1. There is still no code for RaisePropertyChanged - in my implementations i prefer passing the property name as a string, like so: `RaisePropertyChanged("MyProperty");`. 2. I know this is very very lame but you can just do a test run with this - create an empty Label and bind it's visibility to the same source, then bind the grid visibility to label's visibility, like so: `<Label Visibility="{Binding ShowSearch, Converter={StaticResource Bvc}}" x:Name="lbl1" /><Grid Name="Results" Grid.Column="1" Visibility="{Binding ElementName=lbl1, Path=Visibility}">` and see what happens.

Comment: @AndrewRayner 3. Where do you set your DataContext/how do you bind to your VM?

Comment: @zaitsman updated the post above in response to your question

Comment: @AndrewRayner, Can you try changing the setters like so:  `this.RaisePropertyChanged("ShowProvisional");`

Answer (score 0):

You are using different versions of .NET (4.5) on you dev machine, which is only impersontating 4.0 version. It turns out there are some incompatibilities between those two versions (errors which were fixed in 4.5 would not occur even if you are downtargetting 4.0).

In my work with .NET 4.0 (which you are using on your 2003 server), I've found that sometimes `StaticResource` malfunctions in `DataTemplates`. This issue was fixed with 4.5 release, so thats why you do not get those problems. You should change:

**EDIT: Following is not working because Converter is not a dependency property.**

```
Visibility="{Binding ShowSearch, Converter={StaticResource Bvc}}"
```

to

```
Visibility="{Binding ShowSearch, Converter={DynamicResource Bvc}}"
```

Comment: Getting the following message: "A 'DynamicResourceExtension' can only be set on a DependancyProperty of a DependancyObject". Any ideas?

Comment: It seems you cannot do this, because Converter on binding is not a dependency property. My only advice would be to try running it in debugger on new machine without 4.5 installed (you need vs2010 for that) and check the errors.